# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "": syntax error

Tags: python, sql

i keep getting this error when i try to add a column and give it a name

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "100": syntax error
```

here is my code (minimal)

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

conr = sqlite3.connect("CE.db")
curr = conr.cursor()

rt = Tk()


def add():
    ID = e30.get()
    curr.execute('alter table cust add {}'.format(ID))


lbl30 = Label(rt, text= "Your ID")
lbl30.grid  (row = 0, column = 0)

e30 = Entry(rt, width = 30)
e30.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

buttt1 = Button(rt, text = 'Submit', command = add, width = 20)
buttt1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
rt.mainloop()
```

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong and how i can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`curr.execute('alter table cust add {}'.format(ID))`

is being formatted and executed as

`alter table cust add 100`

This is not valid SQLite syntax
The correct syntax can be found at:
[SQlite Alter Syntax](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/tables/alter_table.php)

Comment: is there a way i can make the column name something i put in a entry field in tkinter

Comment: the new column name just needs to be a string not an integer, you probably need a column definition in there too (i.e Not null or similar )

Comment: i went to the website and the first example and it works 100% in DB browser but not in python (VSC)

Comment: i added TEXT as the type at the end and used the str() method, but that didn't work

Comment: "100" is not a valid column name.

Comment: would something like 100's feedback (100 being the ID number) be good or does it have to be all leters

Comment: Try curr.execute('alter table cust add "{}"'.format(ID))

Comment: last question why did doing what you last answer was work so well

Comment: Because you escape the the column name in quotes.  Which conforms to SQLite syntax